# Cassandra: operating a cluster with very different machines

Tags: cassandra

I have a development machine and we are transitioning to production. However the machine is not too bad:

```
HOST: HP - ProLiant BL460c G7 - CZJ20601RL
PROC: 2 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5660 @ 2.80GHz; HT is on (total: 24 thread(s))
RAM : 6 x 2048 MB (total: 11895 MB)
DISK: 2 x 300 GB SAS
```

but the disks are rather small.

The two other production machines will have larger disk. How can I make sure that I don't fill up the disk of the first machine? Is I do what's going to happen?

I thought about reducing the number of "tokens" (vnodes): 256 on the two production machines and only 64 on this one.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about reducing the number of "tokens" (vnodes)

Tuning the number of vnodes tokens is a good way to size the load on a cluster with different hardware.

However, it's all about guessing. Ideally if your high-end servers has x2 CPU, x2 memory and x2 disk bandwidth, you can do a x2 scaling with vnodes tokens.

In your case, it's more complicated because the hardware-scaling factor is not so obvious.

> How can I make sure that I don't fill up the disk of the first machine?

System monitoring. Also, **OpsCenter** can give you metrics about system disk usage if you install the agents on each server

Comment: Thanks (a second time)! OpsCenter seems discontinued for > 2.1 is there another similar tool (I looked on PlanetCassandra but they all seem old and not really doing much).

Comment: Well, if you're only interested by the monitoring par of OpsCenter, you can plug into Cassandra any JMX-compliant monitoring tool. After all all Cassandra metrics are exposed by JMX. For system metrics monitoring (disk space, cpu usage ...) there are also a lot of available tools out there. If you're loaded, you can have the enterprise version of Opscenter, which will support Cassandra >2.1